# Clicking a button on a webpage with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to click on a button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn__primary--large" data-cie-control-urn="checkpoint_remember_me_save_info_yes">Remember</button>
```

I tried `driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//span/button[text()='Remember'][1]")).click()` But got the following error: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

Also tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'btn__primary--large')]").click()` but no click has been made and got the error: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(), 'btn__primary--large')]"}`

Comment: Can you provide the link to the web page to see what the correct locator of the element you are looking for?

Comment: The url is https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/lg/login-submit and its coming up after a succefull login from the url: https://www.linkedin.com/login

Comment: OK, I see the element there. The `xpath` I gave you previously in my answer is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `//button[@data-cie-control-urn='checkpoint_remember_me_save_info_yes']` `xpath`

Comment: I get the error 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable, from the following line: driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//button[@data-cie-control-urn='checkpoint_remember_me_save_info_yes']")).click()

Comment: Maybe you should add some delay to let the element completely loaded before clicking on it?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why `driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//button[@data-cie-control-urn='checkpoint_remember_me_save_info_yes']")).click()` didnt worked,

but `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-cie-control-urn='checkpoint_remember_me_save_info_yes']").click()` works like a charm.

Comment: What's because I sent you a Java code while you are using Python :)

Comment: No, it was even not my fault. I sent you `xpath` only. Anyway, I'm happy it helped you.
So, if possible, accept my answer